# How does Urban Shadows: Second Edition differ from the original?

Tags: edition-comparison, urban-shadows, urban-shadows-2e

Urban Shadows: Second Edition is currently only available as [a quickstart PDF on DriveThruRPG](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/333500/Urban-Shadows-2nd-Ed-Quickstart). As I wait for my physical copy to arrive, I'm wondering:

What significant things were specifically changed from the first edition of Urban Shadows to the second edition?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The *Urban Shadows: Second Edition* Kickstarter campaign](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/magpiegames/urban-shadows-second-edition) outlined the major changes:

> - revised basic moves, including new versions of turn to violence and let it out
> - revised playbooks, including rebuilt versions of The Hunter and The Oracle
> - two brand new playbooks: The Sworn (Power) and The Imp (Wild)
> - changing Factions to Circles and adding Circle Status to represent standing
> - a new downtime phase of the game focused on player-facing city moves and rumors
> - replacing Storms with a new MC-facing faction turn, including new faction moves
> - expanded MC tools for generating your city and Circles at the start of play
>
> We’re also adding a new mechanic to bring PCs into contact more often with each other: City Hubs.

**Turn to violence** replaces **unleash an attack**; compared to the original, it’s much more risky. On a hit, you always inflict harm as established, but your opponent always chooses how they affect you, rather than you choosing what you lose on a 7-9. In addition you now only get an extra benefit (i.e. inflict terrible harm or take something from them) on a 10+. So basic violence is a lot more dangerous. This adds another temptation to mark corruption for moves with more powerful attacks.

Speaking of which: the new version of **let it out** fulfils the same basic function as the original, but instead of having a single list of generic abilities (extend your senses etc), it’s now specific to each playbook. Each archetype lists four abilities for *let it out*, ranging from mortal talents like drawing attention to something or jury-rigging a bomb, to supernatural powers like a Spectre teleporting to their anchor or the unnatural strength of a Vamp or Wolf. When you *let it out*, you choose which one of those abilities you’re using before you roll (a change made in the last revision (5.0) of the QuickStart). Some of the abilities are fairly specific, while others are almost as open-ended as the original generic versions. They’re a mix of new options and existing ones that previously lived elsewhere, allowing for fewer separate moves and more specific guidance on the basic abilities of each archetype.

The renaming of Factions to **Circles** is meant to highlight that characters in a Circle are not all members of an aligned group; the term Faction has been repurposed to mean a specific group within a Circle, including werewolf packs, vampire clans, wizard colleges and so on. Those Factions have their own moves, both for players and the MC (see below). On a minor note, the “Mortality” Faction has been renamed and is now the Circle “Mortalis”.

**Circle Status** is a rating of 0 to 3 representing the trust and esteem in which members of a Circle hold a character. To start a character has a status of 1 in their own Circle, and 0 in others; they can increase this with XP, though they can never have more than 1 status with each of the other Circles. The existing Faction stats, now called **Circle ratings**, still represent how well you understand each Circle, but now you have a separate way to track what they think of you. (Note that it’s made explicit that other Circles will never treat you as one of their own.)

Status is rolled for the City Moves made as part of the new Faction turn, as well as in the revised **refuse to honour a debt** move; it uses a modifier equal to the difference between your status and that of the person you owe, making relative status important.

City Hubs are smaller parts of the city which represent a “collection of institutions, relationships, and anchors—important NPCs—that create a background for the action in your story”. The book outlines four, one associated with each Circle, and the assumption is a game will start with one and add more through play.

There are other extras added via stretch goals on the campaign, including:

- updated versions of six of the extra playbooks for first edition (though these are not in the core book): the Dragon, Immortal, Anointed (a renamed Hallowed), Revenant, Scholar and Vessel
- four additional new playbooks which will be available as extra PDFs: the Angel, Witch, Restless and Ancient
- four additional City Hubs, also as extra PDFs